# spans of distinct sets of vector space basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let basis of $V$ vector space  $S = \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$.
Let's divide this set into two distinct sets $S_1$ and $S_2$.

So are $Sp(S_1)$ and $Sp(S_2)$ distinct sets?

Intuitively, i can say that $Sp(S_1)$ and $Sp(S_2)$ are distinct sets. But how can i prove that systematically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is first worth noting that the span of any set of vectors contains the zero vector, so the spans of $S_1$ and $S_2$ are in fact never disjoint. Clearly other than this trivial case though, they should be.

Well, if the two spans are *not* disjoint, they must have an element in common. But if there is a vector in the span of both, then a linear combination of vectors in $S_1$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors in $S_2$, so

$$\alpha_1 a_1 + \alpha_2 a_2 + \dots + \alpha_k a_k = \beta_1 a_{k+1} + \beta_2 a_{k+2} + \dots + \beta_m a_{n}$$

(with not all $\alpha_i, \beta_i = 0$)

Subtracting the vectors in $S_2$ from both sides gives

$$\alpha_1 a_1 + \alpha_2 a_2 + \dots + \alpha_k a_k - \beta_1 a_{k+1} - \beta_2 a_{k+2} - \dots - \beta_m a_{n} = 0$$

and then clearly linear independence of $S$ is explicitly violated because we can express the zero vector as a linear combination of the vectors with some nonzero coefficients. Hence, $S$ is not a basis and we have a contradiction.

Another thing worth noting is that we really only need to assume linear independence of $S$ here. Whether or not $S$ is a *basis* for $V$ is irrelevant—it may span the whole space or not. We should really prove that linear independence implies this property by proving that its negation implies linear dependence, and your statement is the contrapositive of this.

**Edit:** I just came across this question again and a simpler argument occurred to me.

The two sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ are actually each a basis for a subspace of $V$. Hence, any vector in either subspace is expressible uniquely in the respective basis. So if we had a vector in the span of both, it would be expressible in two different ways (if we consider the original basis, the union of the two sets), which is clearly a contradiction.

This is essentially the same argument as above—just less algebraic and perhaps slightly more intuitive.